# How can I decide css class name dynamically in PHP ?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I want to decide a css class dynamically using ternary operator in PHP,I'm using following code but its some error

```
echo '<div '.count($photos) > 1 ? "class='slider'" : "class='image'".'>';
```

what's wrong in above code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need parentheses for the expression.

```
echo '<div ' . (count($photos) > 1 ? "class='slider'" : "class='image'") . '>';
```

Or

```
echo '<div class="' . (count($photos) > 1 ? 'slider' : 'image') . '">'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,is it above one is better or by keeping all above code in one variable then applying class is better ?

Comment: @Yashwant Just choose the clean one you think.